# how can I save data using html

Tags: javascript, html

how can i save some data on webpage?? i want website that can save data about election votes and then I will Crawl the data to calculate all the votes. because i need to check all the class in highschool.  i made this and it works but it works on only my computer. if another coumputer saves some data on webpage, I can't check the data in my computer. i think local storage is wrong way. in short, i want to make webpage that can save data that everyone can see. because i have to crawl that data to calculate votes in my highschool. i know it is not efficient but i learned to crawl so i want to use that. thank you:)

i used localStorage, and i think it doesn't work as i expected. i want the webpage to save data that any computer can see.but it only could be seen to computer that saved the data. so i need another way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>election system </title>
<script>
 function submit_c1() {
  var newItem_c1 = document.createElement("div");
  newItem_c1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("c1").value;
  newItem_c1.onclick = removeItem_c1;
  document.getElementById("list1").appendChild(newItem_c1);
  saveList_c1();
 }

 function removeItem_c1() {
  document.getElementById("list1").removeChild(this);
  saveList_c1();

 function saveList_c1() {
  localStorage.storedList1 = document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML;
 }

 function loadList_c1() {
  document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML = localStorage.storedList1;
  for(var i = 0; i < list1.children.length; i++) {
   list1.children[i].onclick = removeItem_c1;
  }
 }
</script>
```

i expected that in anyone can see saved data on website i made. but the data could be seen to only the computer and not to other computers:)

Comment: That's JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: "I  expected that in anyone can see saved data on website i made. but the data could be seen to only the computer and not to other computers:)" — It's called **local** storage for a reason. You need server-side code if you want to share data between clients.

Comment: sorry give me a sec

Comment: could you give me some code about server-side code?? or some helpful site??? really appreciate you help:)

Comment: You need to have access to some server. Do you have one? If not you could use fire base, or any free php server...

Comment: if it is just for storing data, you can search online for free database storage options that can be accessed with JavaScript. Amazon AWS and Google have some

Comment: Why is this post downvoted so much? :P

Answer (score 0):

You need a back-end for this. `localStorage` only stores it in the **user's** browser, and will be gone when the user clears his cache. (After all, it's called **local** storage)

Here's a very easy to set up back-end, including a database: https://firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

As Maria said, the JavaScript solutions like LocalStorage and the API IndexedDB are for storing data in the user's browser and are avaiable only in the same. I also suggest you that you mount a back-end structuring the database (relational like SQL or NoSQL like MongoDB), and for logic to persist them, use some server language like PHP, Java, C# or NodeJS.